# Fail to access DOM element in Vue component when using generic javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to dynamic to update data from Vue.compnent by using jQuery way on Webpack project. following is code snippet.

```
<template>
    <div id="container">
        <slot>show string!!</slot>
        <div id="s_container"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}

const items = [
  'thingie',
  'anotehr thingie',
  'lots of stuff',
  'yadda yadda'
]

function listOfStuff () {
  let full_list = ''

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    full_list = full_list + '<li>{{items[i]}}</li>'
  }
  //  const contain = document.querySelector('#s_container')
  const contain = this.$el.querySelector('#s_container')
  if (contain != null) { 
      contain.innerHTML = '<ul ${full_list} </ul>' 
  } else {
     console.log('contain is null');
  }
}
listOfStuff()
</script>
```

but this contain variable is always fail to get #s_container element. How can I get it correctly from outside java script? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to bind your items array into a data return function like this:

```
export default {
 data()
  return {
   items: ['thingie', 'yadda yadda']
  }
}
```

Then you can use a v-for loop the display this array into a HTML li.
Like this into your template:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <ul>
     <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key=index>
      {{ item }}
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this way you can render a simple list using vue.js, if you need more informations about this feature read this part of the documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Have a good day !

Comment: Great first answer Jérémy. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, however, If I would like to use , ex, jQuery way to finish same thing.. how should I get DOM element correctly>